# Why do i get a blank form when I try to call the class in java

Tags: java, class

I am trying to create an ATM simulation in java.
I am having some problem in calling another class.. When I run WithdrawCash class it runs perfect but when I call it in FastCash by choosing from the options a blank form appears.

Below is the code for WithdrawCash:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;`
import java.awt.event.*;

public class WithdrawCash extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

public static void main(String args[]){
    WithdrawCash frame=new WithdrawCash();
    frame.setBounds(400,300,400,150);
    frame.createGUI();
    frame.setTitle("Withdraw Cash Menu:");
    frame.setVisible(true);
}//closes main

private JLabel title, menu;
private JTextField  number;
private JButton SUBMIT;

    private void createGUI(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container wm=getContentPane();
        wm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        title = new JLabel("Please choose from the options below (a-d):");
        menu = new JLabel("a)Fast Cash b)Normal Cash c)Main Menu d)Logout");
        number = new JTextField(10);
        SUBMIT = new JButton("SUBMIT");

        wm.add(title);
        wm.add(menu);
        wm.add(number);
        wm.add(SUBMIT);
        SUBMIT.addActionListener(this);
    }//closes createGUI

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                String value1=number.getText();
                String a,b,c,d,A,B,C,D;

                if(number.getText().length()==0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter the menu option");
                    number.requestFocus();
                }//closes if

                    switch(value1){
                        case "a":
                        case "A": //Fast Cash
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fast Cash");
                        break;

                        case "b":
                        case "B": //Normal Cash
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Normal Cash");
                        break;

                        case "c":
                        case "C": //Main Menu
                        new AccountOpen().setVisible(true);
                        this.dispose();
                        break;

                        case "d":
                        case "D": //Logout
                        this.dispose();
                        break;

                        default:
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid option!! Please type between a-d");
                        number.setText(null);
                        number.requestFocus();
                    }//closes switch
            }//closes actionPerformed
}//closes WithdrawCash
```

And the code for FastCash:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class FastCash extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

public static void main(String args[]){
    FastCash frame=new FastCash();
    frame.setBounds(400,300,400,150);
    frame.createGUI();
    frame.setTitle("Fast Cash Menu:");
    frame.setVisible(true);
}//closes main

private JLabel title, menu, menu2;
private JTextField  number;
private JButton SUBMIT;

    private void createGUI(){
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Container fc=getContentPane();
            fc.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            title = new JLabel("Please choose from the options below (1-10):");
            menu = new JLabel("1)500 2)1000 3)2000 4)5000 5)10000 6)15000");
            menu2 = new JLabel("7)20000 8)Withdrawal menu 9)Main Menu 10)Logout");
            number = new JTextField(10);
            SUBMIT = new JButton("SUBMIT");

            fc.add(title);
            fc.add(menu);
            fc.add(menu2);
            fc.add(number);
            fc.add(SUBMIT);
            SUBMIT.addActionListener(this);
    }//closes createGUI


            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evnt){
                int value1=Integer.parseInt(number.getText());

                if(number.getText().length()==0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter the menu option");
                    number.requestFocus();
                }//closes if

                    switch(value1){

                        case 1:
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "500");
                        break;

                        case 2:
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "1000");
                        break;

                        case 3:
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "2000");
                        break;

                        case 4:
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "5000");
                        break;

                        case 5:
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "10000");
                        break;

                        case 6:
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "15000");
                        break;

                        case 7:
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "20000");
                        break;

                        case 8:
                        new WithdrawCash().setVisible(true);
                        this.dispose();
                        break;

                        case 9: //Main Menu
                        new AccountOpen().setVisible(true);
                        this.dispose();
                        break;

                        case 10:
                        this.dispose();
                        break;

                        default:
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid option!! Please type between 1-10");
                        number.setText(null);
                        number.requestFocus();  
                    }//closes switch
            }//closes actionPerformed
}//closes FastCash
```

Nb: When I try to open AccountOpen (my main menu) it opens perfect from my FastCash class then what's the problem in WithdrawCash class?

Please help me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code for AccountOpen?

Answer (score 1):

Especially in event handlers (actionPerformed) but also on `frame.setVisible(true);` one should call

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnabble() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // ...Old code of actionPerformed here...
        }
    });
}
```

When in actionPerformed, you are on the event handling thread, and should return fast, to leave the GUI responsive. Also other events are not handled.

So the above ensures the enclosed code is done a bit later.

---

***Above answer did not solve it.***

Fast solution: in FastCash add the initialisation.

```
        case 8:
            new WithdrawCash().setVisible(true);
```

Should become

```
        case 8:
            WithdrawCash frame = new WithdrawCash();
            frame.setBounds(400, 300, 400, 150);
            frame.createGUI();
            frame.setTitle("Withdraw Cash Menu:");
            frame.setVisible(true);
```

And `createGUI` must no longer be `private`.

Other things should be said on the style; createGUI could go into the constructor. But I already caused you work enough.

Comment: @rancidfishbreath

Below is my code for AccountOpen:


import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class AccountOpen extends JFrame{
  public static void main(String[] args){
  AccountOpen frame=new AccountOpen();
   frame.setSize(200,200);
   //frame.createGUI();
   frame.setTitle("Main Menu:");
   frame.setVisible(true);
 }
 }

P.S: Sorry am new to this forum so i dont know how to edit this comment

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to say.. where should I keep that code?

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit short, extended the answer.

Comment: Hey I tried the code but it didn't work and now also AccountOpen class opens blank... when I used the code you gave.